# How to run a pkill when invoking a shell to execute a string of commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, process

To automate a system administration task, I wrote down the following line of shell code:

```
bash -c 'pkill -TERM -f java; true'
```

The problem is that pkill kills the bash immediately after the `pkill` command executes, and therefore subsequent commands do not have a chance to execute.

Apart from splitting the them into two lines:

```
bash -c 'pkill -TERM -f java'
bash -c 'true'
```

Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `sleep 60 & bash -c 'pkill -TERM -f sleep; echo true'` kills `sleep` but still prints "true" to the terminal. A trick sometimes used with `grep` may help, though: `bash -c 'pkill -TERM -f \java; true'`.

Comment: @chepner the problem cannot be reproduced in osx, you should be able to reproduce it in linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to kill all java processes, simply drop the `-f`:

```
bash -c 'pkill -TERM java; true'
```

If you really also want to kill non-java processes like `mplayer "jungle_gremlins_of_java.avi"`, the typical "solution" is to rewrite the command so that the pattern doesn't match itself:

```
bash -c 'pkill -TERM -f "[j]ava"; true'
```